# How do I remove a default file from runtimepath?

Tags: vimrc, original-vim

I have this line in vimrc but it seems do nothing.

`set runtimepath-=~/scoop/apps/vim-nightly/current/filetype.vim`

This file is from `$VIMRUNTIME`. I don't want to use vim default filetype settings. How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot remove a single file from `runtimepath`. `runtimepath` is a list of directories. Why don't you want to use Vim's default filetype settings? Do you have files that are not recognized correctly? Or are there filetype dependent settings that you don't like?

Comment: I'm using vim-polyglot and it's better than default. So can you give me a way to remove that?

Comment: I have no experience with vim-polyglot, but there is a note on the [repository's web site](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot#no-ftdetect) on how to disable ftdetect autocommands. Is it that what you want?

Comment: It's not ftdetect autocommands, it is a individual file.

Comment: As written above you cannot remove a single file from the runtime path (except by deleting it physically, but then it will re-appear on the next update). Is it really the file mentioned above that you want to remove? This file is responsible for detecting the different file types, but not for setting options based on the detected file type. Unless you have very special demands I would not recommend to remove this file.

Comment: Vim-polyglot is dependent plugin. It supports better than default. It takes lot of  time  when loading vim, so I don't want to use it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what your problem is. vim-polyglot is neither a single file that you can remove, nor is it some default file or plugin coming with Vim. If you want to remove that plugin completely you should know how you have installed it and uninstall it. (If you installed it via Vim's package mechanism you can temporarily disable it by replacing the `/start/` part of its installation path with `/opt/` and load it only on demand.)

Comment: @JürgenKrämer I understand. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jürgen said in the comments the only way to remove a built-in file from the runtime directories is by physically removing the file (which will reappear after the next upgrade). But I think the issue here is to understand what the files do:

If you look at the content of `$VIMRUNTE/filetype.vim` you will see a bunch of guards and helper functions but the most important lines are the ones looking like this:

```
" 8th (Firth-derivative)
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.8th         setf 8th
```

What they do is that they create autocommands triggered on [`:h BufNewFile`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufNewFile) and [`:h BufRead`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufRead) (so basically when you open a file in a buffer) and they call [`:h :setf`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Asetf). What does `setf` do? The doc says:

```
Set the 'filetype' option to {filetype}, but only if
not done yet in a sequence of (nested) autocommands.

This is short for:

    :if !did_filetype()
    :  setlocal filetype={filetype}
    :endif

This command is used in a filetype.vim file to avoid
setting the 'filetype' option twice, causing different
settings and syntax files to be loaded.
```

Now if you look at the file [`autoload/polyglot/init.vim`](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/blob/master/autoload/polyglot/init.vim) in polyglot you will find the commands run when the plugin is loaded. And what they globally do is setting up autocommands running `setf` when a file is loaded in a buffer.

You probably noticed the following sentence from `:h :setf`: "This command is used in a filetype.vim file to avoid setting the 'filetype' option twice".

So what this means is that `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` is used to set the filetype of some files, and so is polyglot's `init()` function. There is a union on some filetypes between these two files, but they don't conflict because `setf` is made to avoid conflicts. And since polyglot installed the actual filetype plugins, these are the ones which are used when a filetype is set.

So the conclusion of all of that is that you shouldn't bother to disable or remove this `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` because at best it won't change anything and at worst it will prevent the filetypes not covered by polyglot but covered by vim to be set up.

---

Note: I'm not familiar with polyglot and all of the above was deduced from a quick look around. If there are some edge cases I overlooked or if you are facing an actual issue you should explicitly explain it to us.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detail answer, I appreciate that. Now I can understand more about vim.